# Issue of capacity in push back function

Tags: c++, class, capacity

I am facing an issue of trying to get the initial capacity to match with the correct one. I have been trying to get the starting capacity to start at 0 instead of 1 (as shown below). However, I can't seem to do it. I would really appreciate if you can tell me where I've gone wrong with my codes. Thank you in advance!

Correct output:

```
********** TestPush **********
Empty array:
(size=0, capacity=0)
push_back 5 floats:
0  (size=1, capacity=1)
0      1  (size=2, capacity=2)
0      1      2  (size=3, capacity=4)
0      1      2      3  (size=4, capacity=4)
0      1      2      3      4  (size=5, capacity=8)
pop_back until empty:
0      1      2      3  (size=4, capacity=8)
0      1      2  (size=3, capacity=8)
0      1  (size=2, capacity=8)
0  (size=1, capacity=8)
(size=0, capacity=8)
```

Incorrect output:

```
********** TestPush **********
Empty array:
(size=0, capacity=1)
push_back 5 floats:
0  (size=1, capacity=1)
0      1  (size=2, capacity=2)
0      1      2  (size=3, capacity=4)
0      1      2      3  (size=4, capacity=4)
0      1      2      3      4  (size=5, capacity=8)
pop_back until empty:
0      1      2      3  (size=4, capacity=8)
0      1      2  (size=3, capacity=8)
0      1  (size=2, capacity=8)
0  (size=1, capacity=8)
(size=0, capacity=8)
```

My .h file

```
template <typename T>
class vector 
{

private:
 T* v;
 int count;
 int capacity;
public:

vector(void){

    v = new T[capacity];
    count = 0;
    capacity=0;
    capacity++;
}
void push_back(const T& t)
{
    if(count+1>capacity)
{
    capacity *= 2;
    T* newData = new T[capacity];
    for(int i=0; i <count; i++)
    {
        newData[i] = v[i];
    }
    delete[] v;
    v = newData;
}

v[count++] = t;
}
```

main file:

```
void TestPush(void)
{
std::cout << "\n********** TestPush **********\n";
cs150::vector<float> a;
std::cout << "Empty array:\n";
Print(a);

std::cout << "push_back 5 floats:\n";
for (float i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    a.push_back(i);
    Print(a);
}

std::cout << "pop_back until empty:\n";
while (!a.empty()) {
    a.pop_back();
    Print(a);
}
}
```

Comment: You always increment `capacity` immediately after serring it to `0` `capacity=0;
    capacity++; // <<<<<<` so what do you expect?

Comment: i've already tried without the capacity++, it doesn't work. My output for capacity all becomes 0.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] reproducing your problem. How are you accessing `capacity` and outputting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems fairly clear, this is your code

```
vector(void){

    v = new T[capacity];
    count = 0;
    capacity=0;
    capacity++;
}
```

Don't increment the capacity, do this instead

```
vector() {    
    count = 0;
    capacity = 0;
    v = new T[capacity];
}
```

Note that you must set the `capacity` variable before you do `new T[capacity];`
`void` is unecessary BTW

Now since your capacity is one less than previously you need some other changes

```
void push_back(const T& t)
{
    if(count+1>capacity)
    {
        capacity *= 2;
```

becomes

```
void push_back(const T& t)
{
    if (count+1>capacity)
    {
        capacity = std::max(2*capacity, 1);
```

So that if the capacity is zero before it will be one afterwards

Comment: I would use `if (count==capacity)` instead of `if (count+1>capacity)`. And if you are going to introduce STL algorithms, then you may as well replace the manual copy loop with `std::copy()` instead

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using `capacity` in the line

```
v = new T[capacity];
```

before `capacity` has been initialized. That is cause for undefined behavior.

You should initialize `capacity` to a value greater than 0 first.

```
vector(void) : count(0), capacity(1) 
{
    v = new T[capacity];
}
```